# Why BMP file format last line of image is first line on file?

Tags: image

I'm studying Microsoft Windows Bitmap File Format, extension BMP.
I'm curious to know why scanlines are stored on file from bottom to up: the last scanline on image is the first line on file and the first scanline on image is the last line on file.
The documents that I have read do not explain it.

Comment: That...is entirely a matter of taste and how you define your image data layout. There is no universal "first" or "last". 50% of formats store them bottom-up and 50% top-down. The first line in the file *is* the first scanline because it's...the first scanline in the file's order. What you *could* argue is that Windows normally prefers a top-down coordinate system in the rest of its 2D operations (although, that's also largely configurable). In light of *that context* this layout might indeed seem unusual. But don't fall in the trap of thinking there's a universal order the file ought to have.

Answer (score 7):

> Here's a quote from Petzold:
>
> > So, in DIBs, the bottom row of the image is the first row of the file,
> >     and the top row of the image is the last row in the file. This is
> >     called a bottom-up organization. Because this organization is
> >     counterintuitive, you may ask why it's done this way.
> >
> > Well, it all goes back to the OS/2 Presentation Manager. Someone at
> >     IBM decided that all coordinate systems in PM—including those for
> >     windows, graphics, and bitmaps—should be consistent. This provoked a
> >     debate: Most people, including programmers who have worked with
> >     full-screen text programming or windowing environments, think in terms
> >     of vertical coordinates that increase going down the screen. However,
> >     hardcore computer graphics programmers approach the video display from
> >     a perspective that originates in the mathematics of analytic geometry.
> >     This involves a rectangular (or Cartesian) coordinate system where
> >     increasing vertical coordinates go up in space.
> >
> > In short, the mathematicians won. Everything in PM was saddled with a
> >     bottom-left origin, including window coordinates. And that's how DIBs
> >     came to be this way.
>
> **Source:** Charles Petzold, *Programming for Windows 5th Edition*, Chapter
>   15.

from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346115/why-are-bmps-stored-upside-down